# importing files from bitbucket / jira and store it in my backend

Tags: import

I m creating an application using react/node express, I m providing an interface to the user containing a button named import: I want to do this: when the user clicks on this button a popup window will appear to him to connect to his bitbucket and when he connects he choose the repository and files he wants to import and click on the ok button that is set in that popup window, the file chosen by the user will be stored in a folder in the backend folder. I m using vs code to write the code

I tried to look for a similar process over the internet / YouTube and forums and i didn't find that much information on this. does anyone know how can i implement this or any resources i can check